# jQuery Transit animation not executing within for loop properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, jquery-animate, nonblocking

I am using [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to animate a changing  element.

I am animating multiple boxes using a for loop.

The javaScript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  $('div.test').mouseover(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      console.log(i+' Starting Loop');

      //Rotate box animation
      $('div.test' && '.'+i).transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        rotateY: '-180deg',
        x: '-90px'
      }, 'slow',function(){
        //On completion code.
        $('div.test' && '.'+i).append(' With Changed Text');
        console.log(i + 'Text has been changed');

        //Rotate back
        $('div.test' && '.'+i).transition({
          perspective: '100px',
          rotateY: '0deg',
          x: '0px'
        }, 'slow');
      });
      console.log(i + 'finished the loop');
      alert(i + ' finished loop');
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
<div class='test 0'>
  Box1
</div>
<div class='test 1'>
  Box2
</div>
</body>
```

It is supposed to work by making the box move, make the appropriate changes, and then move back to its original position.

However, instead of waiting for the first animation to finish before moving on to the next iteration of the for loop, it seems to be waiting until the for loop is finished before it executes the `$.transition()` functions.

So when the `$.transition()` functions are called, `i = 2`. Therefore the `$.append()` function is appending to an element with the class '.2', which does not exist.

Is there any way to make sure the animations execute within the loop properly?

**NOTE** This is a simplified version of my real code. I would normally be appending different values for each box. I am also iterating through a list which could possibly be longer than 2.

**EDIT** I found a solution by recursively iterating through the array. [Here it is.](http://jsfiddle.net/bHsL3/9/)

Comment: Loops are non-blocking. Time for recursion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this has an official answer, here is my new javaScript code.

```
<script>   
function rotateBox(list){
  if (list.length <= 0){
    return;
  }

  var i = list.pop();
  console.log("i: "+i);

  $('div.test' && '.'+i).transition({
    perspective: '100px',
    rotateY: '-180deg',
    x: '-90px'
  }, 'slow',function(){
    //On completion code.
    $('div.test' && '.'+i).append(' With Changed Text');
    console.log(i + 'Text has been changed');

    //Rotate back
    $('div.test' && '.'+i).transition({
      perspective: '100px',
      rotateY: '0deg',
      x: '0px'
    }, 'slow', function(){

      //Recursion!
      rotateBox(list);
    });
  });

}

window.onload = function(){

  //a list of arbitrary values that match with a <div> class
  list = [0, 1];

  $('div.test').mouseover(function(){
    rotateBox(list);

    //Just in case you feel like running through it again
    list = [0, 1];
  });
};
</script>
```

And a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bHsL3/6/.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have the code necessary to animate the boxes back and forth, however, your for loop is executing instantly (thereby firing off the transitions at nearly the same time).

Take a look at this example. You should be able to modify it to loop as many times as necessary.
http://jsfiddle.net/zca33/

Also, I'm not certain that you can combine jQuery selectors with &&, at least, it's not the preferred method. See: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

**EDIT:** Since you're trying to perform the animation on success of an ajax call, you can target the specific box by CSS class. See:
http://jsfiddle.net/zca33/2/

Comment: This would work if I was actually using mouseover. In this example, mouseover is just an arbitrary trigger. 

In the real code, the animations need to be triggered by the success of an ajax request. The request returns a json object containing lists telling the function which boxes to change and what to change them too. All the rotating boxes need to rotate together or in order, unprompted by the user.

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying. So, you perform an ajax request and, on complete, animate the corresponding box. I assume you want to do this by targeting the box by some integer returned in the ajax response?

Comment: That would be correct. Hence the classes named after integers.

Comment: I actually found a solution that works by recursively iterating through an array. [Here it is.](http://jsfiddle.net/bHsL3/6/)